# Virtualbox Ubuntu issues running programs in secure shell

Tags: ssh, gui, virtualization

Hello I am new to Ubuntu and Virtual machines.  I am running windows 8.1 with a VM running XUbuntu.  I am able to secure shell into my work computer (RedHat)through the VM, but when I try to run a Linux based program it becomes frozen or extremely slow and my network usage looks like a roller coaster.  Any ideas for what could cause the slow down?
Thank you

Comment: Is the program you're running text or X?  Have you tried other programs to see if they behave similarly?  Is anyone else similarly using the program over the Internet through ssh?

Comment: The program I am running is GUI based, and other programs are equally slow or unresponsive.  Is there a way to ssh into a computer and use the networked computers resources as opposed to the home computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you log into a remote machine and run programs using X forwarding (well, same is true of text programs, but much less bandwidth) it is running the program (the X client) (client/server terms are reversed for X than what you normally think of) on the remote machine, so it is using its CPU,memory, etc.; however, the display (the X server) is on your local machine, so it's streaming all the X display updates across the Internet to your machine.  Now if you think VNC is slow over the Internet...it's fast compared to raw X.  Using ssh compression *may* help, or it may make things worse, depending on just how slow your Internet connection is.   X just wasn't designed for low-speed high-latency connections, so while it's really cool and handy to be able to do it, performance over anything but a high-speed LAN sucks pond water.

The only way seriously improve performance is going to be to use VNC or FreeNX or something instead of raw X.  If you don't have the ability to install VNC,etc. directly on the machine at work, perhaps you can use another machine up there (even a dedicated VM) to host the VNC server; then you can use that machine to do the X-over-SSH connection where it's on a faster network, and you can VNC to that machine instead of the one you really want.

Comment: Thank you for the information Charles that helped a lot!  I'll  try to get VNC on the work computer.